# U.S. college courses naming system -- how does it work?

Tags: culture

[Example](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdLiRaajwSXSO6FD9_oQUkjAgQoRHDs8d):

> ECO 305: Money and Banking

What do those three letters and the number exactly mean? Could you please give me a brief, general-terms type of introduction to the college courses naming system in the U.S. so that I at least have a basic idea of how this thing works?

Comment: "economics" though I do not know if there is any standard abbreviations for this.

Comment: I would guess: Economy, course number 305.

Comment: Seems off topic because coded naming systems for universities is not about learning English

Comment: Every university has its own system for course codes, which usually involve some combination of unit/department/faculty, level, and section. There is no way to generalize. For example, a business course might be *BUS* or *Bus*, but at my alma mater the undergraduate business department was named *Applied Economics and Management*, and therefore the courses were coded as *AEM*.

Comment: Learning English isn't just about grammar - it's about being able to function in an English-speaking environment. That includes recognizing a course description, being able to order at a restaurant, and tons of silly things that people should totally feel free to ask about. I vote to reopen this, and I will continue to do so for similar questions. This is a free forum after all - you can focus on the questions you like better.

Comment: @CookieMonster, to make a good case for re-opening the question, you may want to re-focus the question on conventions for abbreviations in English and simply provide the university course listings as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system for naming college courses is dependent on the system that the college you're attending uses.  It looks like this comes from [Missouri State University](http://www.missouristate.edu/registrar/catalog/courses_ec.htm).

> **ECO 305 Money and Banking**
>
> *Prerequisite: ECO 155.*
> Nature and functions of money, a survey of the operation and development of the banking system in the U.S.; introduction to monetary theory and policy.
>
> Credit hours: 3 - Lecture contact hours: 3 - Lab contact hours: 0

[My university](http://utexas.edu/) uses a system that, on the surface, looks similar to this one but they're actually quite different (and from a quick glance, I can't tell how MSU numbers courses but it's definitely **not** the same)...

If you're curious how it would be interpreted at my university:

> ECO = economics

The number can be further broken down in this system:

> 3 = 3 hours of coursework per week

So a course with the number 401 would be four credit hours for a semester.

> 0 = freshman level

0 and 1 are lower division courses at the freshman and sophomore level (1st and 2nd year), 2 and up are upper division and graduate level courses

So a course with the number 366 would be an upper division course.

> 5 = specific course number

Generally the first course in a series is 1 followed by 2, 3... etc but the courses don't always have to be taken sequentially or even at all... and sometimes numbers are skipped. Course listings will generally note if there are any prerequisite classes you must take.

So, ECO 305 would be a freshman-level course in the Economics department that is worth three credit hours.

Comment: Interesting. I'd only heard of the hundreds digit in a three-digit course number representing level (1xx=freshman,2xx=sophomore,3xx=junior,4xx=senior,5xx=grad/post-bachelor). Clearly it varies widely by school! Best to check for a legend in the catalog for the college of interest.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some that I've seen:

- ECO/ECON - economics
- MATH - mathematics
- PHYS - physics
- BIO/BIOL - biology
- GEO - geography
- CS - computer science
- PSY/PSYCH - psychology
- PHIL - philosophy
- LIT - literature
- SOC - sociology
- EN - English (literature)
- ENGS - Engineering sciences
- HIST - history
- MUS - music

Comment: Here's the list from University of Washington: http://www.washington.edu/students/crscat/. Note that different colleges might have slightly different versions. Usually the name of the course should point you to the right meaning of the abbreviation.

Comment: GEO could also be geology. Likewise, GEOL or GEOG for Geography.

Answer (score 1):

ECO has the meaning of "economics".