# What does the speaker mean by "Accountancy 2"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am a little confused about the apparently simple but tricky  **'2'** in "Accountancy **2**", when I had thought that it might be **class 2**, later my friend said it might also mean **grade 2**? And a third friend told me it should be **course 2**?

So could anyone help me with this? What is the best explanation or normal assumption to be applied in this context, in a British university?

The context is:

"I" am having a conversation with "she", my sister, who is a college student now and she's really smart. We are close.

Here is the sentence:

> She looked at me, then removed the glasses. ‘You okay? You look like
>   shit.’
>
> ‘So do you.’
>
> ‘I know. I went on this stupid detox diet. It’s given me hives.’ She
>   reached a hand up to her chin.
>
> ‘You don’t need to diet.’
>
> ‘Yeah. Well . . . there’s this bloke I like in **Accountancy 2.** I
>   thought I might start making the effort. Huge hives all over your face
>   is always a good look, right?’
>
> I sat down on the bed. It was my duvet cover.
>
> *Me Before You by Jojo Moyes*

Comment: I’m not entirely sure this is on-topic, but here is a related question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/52559/36187.

Comment: I saw the link, thanks, but it did not solve my question, and it confuses me more. The link did not tell me how to distinct  whether "2" is for course hour, grade or class, and it for the US university. I asked for a British one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it means the second course or the second semester of the accountancy studies.

Like, in some places there is *Economics I* for first year or first semester and then *Economics II* which is a bit advanced. Same is true of other subjects. It is just a more advanced version of the *accountancy* they studied previously.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the speaker is taking a degree such and "Business Adminstration" at university. There are a number of courses that make up the degree. Some of these courses are split into separate parts. *Accountancy 2* is the second part of the accountancy course. It can only be taken by students who have completed the "Accountancy 1" course.

It would be common to have one part of the course per year or per term. So it may be that "Accountancy 1" is taught in the first year (or term) and "Accountancy 2" in the second.

It doesn't really matter on the details. There is a man that the speaker likes, who takes the same course. The speaker is trying to lose weight, but the diet has given them a skin rash.